# How to invoke Inject environment variables to the build process plugin in jenkinsFIle jenkins 2.x with pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to migrate my project from jenkins 1 to jenkins 2.x using pipeline as code or `Jenkinsfile`.
But I don't see any option in snippet generator to generate environment injector plugin into a script in Jenkinsfile.

Anyone can help?

Comment: It's may be good to point out that https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject is not very well supported by pipelines (yet): https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42614

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that **you want to read properties from a specific file and inject them as environment variables?**

If so, this is a solution:

- Create the file that will contain the environment properties

  - You create some properties file called `project.properties` with following content:

    `PROJECT_VERSION='1.4.34'`

Then, on your **pipeline code**, you've to **add the following code** in order to be able to **read the file and inject read variables** as environment variables:

`node {
    load "${WORKSPACE}\\project.properties" // assuming that props file is in 
    Jenkins Job's workspace
    echo "PROJECT VERSION: ${PROJECT_VERSION}"
}`

- First line read and inject variable `PROJECT_VERSION` as environment variable
- Second line is just to print read variable to make sure that everything worked seamlessly

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: be aware that you have to add in your project.properties: env.PROJECT_VERSION="1.4.34" otherwise you can get a space after the 1.4.34 like "1.4.34 "

Comment: what if that variable has to be used in external batch file

Comment: Since the value already exists as an environment variable, you can always get it on your batch scripts by typing %PROJECT_VERSION%.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to just comment on your question, but my lack of reputation is hindering me.

The list of supported steps is here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/

In general, you can use other plugins by using their Java style invocation.

i.e.

```
step([$class: 'classname', parametername: 'value'])
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you show an example with this plugin? Because I'm not sure if it's supported: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42614

Comment: @Sebastian I haven't interacted with Jenkins at this level in some time, but my comment doesn't refer to a specific plugin.  It refers to the implementation of pipelines and Jenkinsfile's in general.  If you have a plugin available to Jenkins but that is not natively supported by the pipeline dsl you can call steps from that plugin using that format as a JSON array of parameters.  https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#understanding-syntax-1

Answer (score 0):

I used this example for read a properties file and use it in a pipeline stage:

```
node(){
    file = readFile('params.txt')
    prop=[:]
    file.eachLine{ line ->
      l=line.split("=")
      prop[l[0]]=l[1]
   }
   withEnv(['MyVar1='+prop["MyVar1"],'MyVar2='+prop["MyVar2"],'MyVar3='+prop["MyVar3]]){        
     stage('RUN_TEST'){
       echo env.MyVar1
       echo env.MyVar2
       echo env.MyVar3
       sh"echo $MyVar1"
     }
  }
}
```